# when i try to send another request to OMDB inside onitemclick method it gives me error?

Tags: java, android, json, jsonresponse

I'm trying to send another request when I click on an item which is a movie to get its plot and year of production but it gives me an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
 Response.Listener < JSONObject > , Response.ErrorListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


   EditText movienameText;
   Button getButton;
   TextView yearText, genreText, titleText, plotText, nameText;
   ListView moviesList;
   private ResourceBundle response;
   ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;
   ArrayList < String > moviesname = new
   ArrayList < String > ();
   ArrayList < String > moviesyear = new
   ArrayList < String > ();
   ArrayList < String > moviesgenre = new
   ArrayList < String > ();
   ArrayList < String > moviesplot = new
   ArrayList < String > ();
   String x, plot, genre, year;
   RequestQueue
   queue;
   @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    movienameText = findViewById(R.id.MovienameText);
    getButton = findViewById(R.id.getButton);
    moviesList = findViewById(R.id.moviesList);
    moviesList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, moviesname);
   }


   public void get(View view) {

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url1 = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + movienameText.getText().toString() + "&apikey=1a382b30";
    JsonObjectRequest request1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, null, this, this);
    queue.add(request1);
   }
   @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {


     for (int i = 0; i < response.getJSONArray("Search").length(); i++) {
      if (i < response.getJSONArray("Search").length()) {
       moviesname.add(response.getJSONArray("Search").getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));

      } else {
       break;
      }
     }
     moviesList.setAdapter(adapter);
     year = response.getString("Year");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) { //       
    genre = response.getString("Genre"); //    
    plot = response.getString("Plot");
    year = response.getString("Year");
    x = moviesList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String url2 = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + moviesList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().replace("
     ","
     ")+" & apikey = 1 a382b30 ";
     JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2, null, this, this); queue.add(request2); AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); builder.setMessage(x).create().show(); builder.setMessage(year).create().show(); //       builder.setMessage(genre).create().show();  //      
     builder.setMessage(plot).create().show();
    }
  }
```

Comment: your code is not readable as well as not formattable.

Comment: I will try to make it more readable.

Comment: What the error do you have?

Comment: when I click on an item which is a movie there is no response come back from OMDB, as you can see request 2 in (onItemClick), doesn't return year response.